# x509: certificate relies on legacy Common Name field, use SANs or temporarily enable Common Name matching with GODEBUG=x509ignoreCN=0

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I have a registry server at https://test-docker-hub.test.net

- On Ubunutu 18.04:

  mkdir /etc/docker/certs.d/test-docker-hub.test.net/

  cp test-docker-hub-selfsigned.crt
  /etc/docker/certs.d/test-docker-hub.test.net/test-docker-hub-selfsigned.crt

  docker pull working fine
- On Ubuntu 20.04:

  mkdir /etc/docker/certs.d/test-docker-hub.test.net/

  cp test-docker-hub-selfsigned.crt
  /etc/docker/certs.d/test-docker-hub.test.net/test-docker-hub-selfsigned.crt

  docker pull giving following error

  ```
  Error response from daemon: Get
  "https://test-docker-hub.test.net/v2/": x509: certificate relies on
  legacy Common Name field, use SANs or temporarily enable Common Name
  matching with GODEBUG=x509ignoreCN=0
  ```

I setup docker using

```
curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com -o get-docker.sh
sudo sh get-docker.sh
```

Any help on this would be very useful.

Answer (score 2):

you can add  /etc/docker/daemon.json  with "insecure-registries"["https://test-docker-hub.test.net"],and restart docker service,docker loign successfully,hopes help you.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

it worked for me. I created a file /etc/docker/daemon.json and added:

("insecure-registries": ["https://test-docker-hub.test.net"]) and i could access the container registry in GitLab.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).